# Python Scapy Attribute error

Tags: scapy

```
>>> ans, unans = srp([your
```

packet here], iface='wlan0')

> > > ans.summary()

This gives me error : "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'summary'
"

Comment: Your srp function returned a NoneType object that you stored in the ans variable. Trying to call the summary() or any other function on this NoneType object will return an AttributeError.

The srp function probably have a documentation detailing how to use it.

Comment: `help(srp)`. This means that no answer packet were received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When no answer is received in time (timeout), `None` is returned by `srp`

You should be checking for a None result

Comment: Yes 
The "None Type" was because no answer was returned i.e. None. 
type(None)="None Type"